# Read UTF8 Char from FileStream

Tags: vb.net, filestream, utf

I need a way to read from a `FileStream` every single char. Char by Char.
Every time I read a char, I need to increment the `FileStream.Position`.

I am trying the code snippet, but it returns more than one char:

```
Dim bytes(1) As Byte

Dim nBytes As Integer = oFile.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)
Dim nChars As Integer = decoder8.GetCharCount(bytes, 0, nBytes)
Dim chars(nChars - 1) As Char
nChars = decoder8.GetChars(bytes, 0, nBytes, chars, 0)
Return New String(chars, 0, nChars)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `StreamReader` and it's [`Read`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ath1fht8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method instead, couldn't you?

```
Using rd = New StreamReader("path", Encoding.UTF8)
    While rd.Peek() >= 0
        Dim c As Char = Chr(rd.Read())
        Console.WriteLine("Next character: " & c)
    End While
End Using
```

> `StreamReader.Read`
>
> Reads the next character from the input stream and advances the
>   character position by one character.

Comment: No, I can't because the FileStream is used several time inside a specific namespace

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `oFile` is of type `FileStream` then

```
Dim nBytes As Integer = oFile.ReadByte()
```

should work.